# 301 Redirect specific pages in webconfig IIS7

Tags: .net, redirect, iis-7, web-config, http-status-code-301

I'm trying to redirect a couple specific pages on my site using the web.config file.  Most of these pages not only no longer exist but the folder structure doesn't exist anymore either.
For example mysite.com/oldfolder/index.aspx no longer exists oldfolder doesn't exist.  So I would like to make a case in my project's web.config that says "all requests to /oldfolder/index.aspx now go to /newfolder/index.aspx."  I've done some digging and this seems to make the most sense:

```
  <location path="oldfolder/index.aspx">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="newfolder/index.aspx" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

But it acts like it's not even there and throws and error when I try going to oldfolder/index.aspx.  What am I doing wrong?  Or am I attacking this in the wrong way altogether?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I didn't have HTTP Redirect turned on in my local IIS.  (Which the tutorial I read failed to mention).  So it works now that IIS will let me redirect!